# How can i log warnings when i run apache benchmark

Tags: php, apache2

How can i log warnings when i run apache benchmark.

I ran this command ab -n10000 -c100 http://crossroads/blog (Locally)

But none of the request is logged in to apache log file.

When i tried the same link in the browser it logged all the entries. Almost 100 entry in each request.

Can anyone help me how can i populate log entry with `ab` command ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Basic input/output redirection](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/io-redirection.html), could be a great way to add flexibility to your small one liner start up scripts. You should be able to redirect things where they need to, but this will depend on how you design your app.
Maybe trying something as simple as this could work for you:

```
command ab -n10000 -c100 http://crossroads/blog 2>&1 logfile.log
```

Ab may already have a logfile parameter it seems it would be natural. But above code example show the nice flexibility of io redirections, redirects all error returns **and** program output to same logfile.

It's an easily overlooked yet powerful technique integrated  in many shell scripts, but not tried with ab though.

I would really of thought ab would have a log file parameter or something of the sort.

Good-luck